# Neo4j - Total relationships from Node

Tags: neo4j

First let me point out that I am new to Neo4j, if there is a better way to do this please let me know.

Secondly, how can I also find out:

```
// QUERY
if(!empty($_SESSION['uid'])) {
    $uid = $_SESSION['uid'];
    $query = 'MATCH (cu:User)
    WHERE cu.id = "'.$uid.'"
    WITH cu
    MATCH (p:Painting)<-[:PAINTED]-(u:User)-[:LIVES_IN]->(l:Location) 
    WHERE (p.slug) = "'.$slug.'"
        RETURN p,u,l, 
        EXISTS((cu)-[:LIKES]->(p)) as liked,
        EXISTS((cu)-[:FOLLOWS]->(u)) as followed,
        SIZE((:User)-[:LIKES]->(p)) as total_likes, 
        SIZE((:User)-[:FOLLOWS]->(u)) as total_follows
    LIMIT 1';    
} else {
    $query = 'MATCH (p:Painting)<-[:PAINTED]-(u:User)-[:LIVES_IN]->(l:Location) WHERE (p.slug) = "'.$slug.'"
        RETURN p,u,l, 
        SIZE((:User)-[:LIKES]->(p)) as total_likes, 
        SIZE((:User)-[:FOLLOWS]->(u)) as total_follows
        LIMIT 1';
}
```

So now I'm running two queries depending on the availability of a user. I have to imagine there must be a better / more efficient way to do this but at least it works for the moment.

Comment: Can you clarify what Total_Likes and Total_Follows should be? We're already returning the number of likes for the painting, and the number of people following the user. Are you trying to get the number of paintings this particular user has liked, and the number of other people this particular user follows? Or something more?

Comment: total_likes = total likes for the painting (p)
total_follows = total follows for the artist (u)
0/1 check to see if current user liked p (0 no / 1 yes)
0/1 check to see if current user followed u (0 no / 1 yes)

Comment: So for this "current user" you want to find out if they liked the painting and followed the painter? How do you find the current user (by ID? by name?) Can you add this "current user" into your query in the description?

Comment: Well I guess that is my problem, I've left out the current user ID. Someone I got it in my head u:User was my user but that is really the owner.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/4cd3a7acfc5728fd6c105d8e38ba020c (it already gives me the information I need, im not sure why id be adding more to it, isnt it just a handing issue?

Comment: Well, that graph shows the painter, the painting, the location, the followers of the painter, and the likers of the painting. So far this "current user" doesn't have a presence here, and since they aren't in the query, we can't be sure they are one of the ones who have liked or followed. Besides, your query above doesn't actually return the followers or the likers, it just gets their count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like there's a concept of a current user, that you'll probably get by ID or name or similar, and you want to see if they like the painting and follow the user for this particular painting defined by its "slug" property (is that a unique value, or does this match to multiple paintings?)

I'll make a stab at this one, and offer some improvements on how to better get the number of likes and follows .

```
MATCH (currentUser:User)
WHERE currentUser.ID = 123
WITH currentUser
MATCH (p:Painting)<-[:PAINTED]-(painter:User)-[:LIVES_IN]->(l:Location) 
WHERE (p.slug) = "blah-blah-blah"
    RETURN p,painter,l, 
    SIZE( (:User)-[:LIKES]->(p) ) as painting_likes, 
    SIZE( (:User)-[:FOLLOWS]->(painter) ) as painter_follows, 
    EXISTS( (currentUser)-[:LIKES]->(p) ) as current_user_liked,
    EXISTS( (currentUser)-[:FOLLOWS]->(painter) ) as current_user_followed
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I updated the question above. I will go through your code.

Comment: Seems to work, however not sure how to handle when currentUser.ID is empty. Which should still return the painting, user, and location. I'm not sure why EXISTS does not return 0 if the match is not present.

Comment: Shouldn't all users have some kind of ID or otherwise unique value? This was just an example, so you should use whatever property makes sense, usually the one used by your unique and existence constraints for :Users. Boolean values in neo4j return booleans, not 0/1 like Oracle and other dbs. You'll get a false if the pattern doesn't exist.

Comment: Well if someone is not logged in obviously they would have no associated user information. However, obviously the details of the painting would still load even if the user ID is not available.

Comment: Updated the main question again with my latest code.

Answer (score 0):

```
MATCH (p:Painting)<-[:PAINTED]-(u:User)-[:LIVES_IN]->(l:Location) WHERE (p.slug) = "blah-blah-blah"
WITH p, u, l
OPTIONAL MATCH (ul:User)-[likes:LIKES]->(p)
OPTIONAL MATCH (uf:User)-[follows:FOLLOWS]->(u)
RETURN p,u,l,ul,uf LIMIT 1
```

This returns the correct graph, I can't figure out why I'm having such a hard time verifying the like / follow connection.

Ugh, I've tried to many things today, I do not know what is up and down anymore. I think the OPTIONAL MATCHES i have now actually handle total values. I guess what I'm having trouble with is verifying if the existing user has liked or followed.

Comment: Generally it's a good idea to edit the problem description to add additional info, and reserve answers for actual solutions to the problem.

Comment: It will be link, below your description, and below the neo4j tag.